# How can I detect photo is taken vertical or not? (I find a way but it does not work)

Tags: java, android, android-camera

### I use this method to detect photo is taken vertical or not from camera :

```
 boolean isVertical = true ;     
        ExifInterface exif2;
        try {
            exif2 = new ExifInterface(path_img);

        int orientation = exif2.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                isVertical = false ; 
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                isVertical =false ; 
                break;
        }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

### But the problem is :

```
orientation
```

s value is always **1**

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: how about `if (height > width)`?

Comment: What if you check width vs height? if h > w, the photo is vertical.

Comment: What happens if you change the exif2.getAttributeInt(ExifIntergface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1)? Do you get -1?

Comment: @kha it gives 1 for huawei p7

Comment: This is very strange. I have the same exact code and it works fine. How are the images taken? Are they taken from an Android device (I imagine they are but just making sure)? Can you (even temporarily) use UniversalImageLoader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and load your image using that library specifying considerExifParams(true) and see if that fixes your problem?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
          int rotate = 0;
                try {
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
                    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                            imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                    }
                    Log.v(Common.TAG, "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: it gives 1 for orientation

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you Create a new Bitmap and then get width and height of it.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("full_path_of_bitmap");
if(bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight())
   // Picture is Landscape.
else
   // Picture is Portrait.
```

Kolay gelsin.

Comment: some phones it s true but some phone for example samsung galaxy tab 3 , it is always says landscape even it is vertical